# filter from the array of objects data based upon values i get from checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter some records coming from my api data, i am trying to use filter but i am not sure how should i do for multipoe items.

Here is my code the api response i have and what happens when i do a checkbox

my APi data

```
{
    "requestId": "",
    "totalRecords": 132,
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "items": [
        {
            "Id": 3489,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {
                "unit": "CAD",
                "value": 10
            },
            "Name": "John Doe"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3508
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {
                "unit": "CAD",
                "value": 10
            },
            "Name": "John Doe"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3503,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {
                "unit": "CAD",
                "value": 25
            },
            "Name": "John Sinth"
        }
    ]
}
```

and in my checkbnox i am passing two checkboxes values which are full object like 3508,3503 but now sure how to do

Here is my code as to what i did but i am not getting filetered records

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.apiData));
                    if (this.multipleSelection.length > 0) {
                        const data = parsedData.filter(function (el)
                        {
                            return el.Id = 3489 and 3503
                        })
                    } else {
                        const data = parsedData;
                    }
```

Comment: If you do: `console.log(typeof this.apiData)` what do you get?

Comment: `3489 and 3503` is invalid JS. Please refer to [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND).

Comment: Also learn about the difference of `=` and `===`

Comment: i know its invalid, but i want to know how do i get the only two objects when i am using filter instead of all 3

Comment: i listed what type of api.Dataq is

Comment: as i mentioned, i know those small things, its a type mistake but i really struggler when i have to filter those objects i need from the rest of the apidata

Comment: You're mentioning some Checkboxes in your UI. How are those related in your code?

Comment: What means *"are full object like 3508,3503"* ? You mean, an (*object*) Array `[3508, 3503]` ?

Comment: the below one is not an asnwer to the question, it assumed the ids a numbers in array which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const data = {
    "requestId": "",
    "totalRecords": 132,
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "items": [
        {
            "Id": 3489,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {"unit": "CAD","value": 10},
            "Name": "John Doe"
        },{
            "Id": 3508,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {"unit": "CAD","value": 10},
            "Name": "John Doe"
        },{
            "Id": 3503,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {"unit": "CAD","value": 25},
            "Name": "John Sinth"
        }
    ]
};

const ids = [3503, 3508];
const parsedData = data.items.filter((item) => ids.includes(item.Id));

console.log(parsedData)
```

if the above is still not clear, here's an example that uses checkboxes:

```js
const data = {
    "requestId": "",
    "totalRecords": 132,
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "items": [
        {
            "Id": 111,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {"unit": "CAD","value": 10},
            "Name": "John Doe"
        },{
            "Id": 222,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {"unit": "CAD","value": 10},
            "Name": "John Doe"
        },{
            "Id": 333,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {"unit": "CAD","value": 25},
            "Name": "John Sinth"
        }
    ]
};


const filterByIds = (ids) => data.items.filter((item) => ids.includes(+item.Id));

const elsIdInputs = document.querySelectorAll("[name='id']");


elsIdInputs.forEach((elId) => {
  elId.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const ids = [...elsIdInputs].filter(el => el.checked).map(el => +el.value);
    console.log(ids)
    if (!ids.length) return; // Exit. (none is checked)
    
    // Else... do something here
    console.clear();
    console.log(filterByIds(ids));
  });
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="111"> 111</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="222"> 222</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="333"> 333</label>
```

Comment: but i have an object, no specify ids with me, so i cannot directly add ids

Comment: @Nocus could you share an example of how that "object" looks like?

Comment: when i check the chbox, the value is going as array of object as: ```[{
            "Id": 3503,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {
                "unit": "CAD",
                "value": 25
            },
            "Name": "John Sinth"
        }]```

Comment: if i select 2 checkboxes, it pass 2 objects inside an array

Comment: i shared with you, how it looks like, if i select one checkbox, it passes the whole row as array of objects and one of such key is id and has a value of 3503

Comment: @Nocus sorry, I see no checkboxes in your question, you gave no context about what `this` is, etc. I'm showing you in this answer basically how to approach your request given the IDs are in an array like `[111,222,333]` and I've used the same data you have.

Comment: @Nocus see in my example the `const ids = [3503, 3508];` line? That's the IDs received from some checkboxes I presume. Is perhaps your question how to get an array of values given some checked checkboxes with the same class or name attribute?

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8euorbd7/, not complete but close, i want to get two matches objects from the api array, which is 3508 and 3505

Comment: select of one checkbox, i get data like this ```"items": [
        {
            "Id": 3489,
            "Status":"Awaiting Funds",
            "amountPaid": {"unit": "CAD","value": 10},
            "Name": "John Doe"
        }]```

Comment: something like this, very very close, the answers is the checkbox data

https://jsfiddle.net/8euorbd7/1/